# interactive software for creating webpages

Tags: html

I want to design an interactive website (with checkboxes, radiobuttons etc.) which I would later link up with a MySQL database. But I don’t know any HTML. Is there any (free) software that enables me to design my website using drag-and-drop of controls and generates the HTML automatically? Which is the best software in your opinion?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to become a web developer but not learn HTML?

Comment: There are tools available.  However, if you're going to work on websites then I _highly_ recommend learning the technologies which drive what you're doing.  (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc.)  Just debugging issues will be _far_ easier if you're familiar with that you're looking at.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I fully intend to learn HTML in the future, but right now time is limited and I cannot expect to learn enough HTML in a short time to create the page I want. Hence my question.

Comment: @David: What tools are you referring to?

Comment: Why is this off-topic? I got 3 answers too, which were informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some good web applications out there such as Weebly and Webs, but if you really want downloadable software, I would suggest Nvu.

Comment: Nvu seems to be promising...can I add checkboxes and radiobuttons using Nvu? I could not find this information anywhere. Maybe you can help me if you have used it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do use HTML to create checkboxes and radiobuttons

Comment: Thanks! Nvu is just what I needed! Sorry can't vote it up, it says I need 15 rep to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Dreamweaver is the best editor for newbies, it is very intuitive, kind of like using Microsoft Word, and it already contains some interactive scripts, for example for integrating a music player on your website. However, to make the website interact with a database, or to store data in any way, you need more than just HTML, you will likely have to learn about PHP or a similar server-side programming language.

Comment: Dreamweaver looks to be too complicated (and expensive) for what I have in mind.Is there a free trial version available?